# create an instance after devise user registration, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to automate the creation of an unrelated model instance after a user signs up through devise, just wondering where and how I would do it?

something like

```
@fan.subscriptions.create(band_id: 1)
```

after a successful registration (fan being the user)

subscription schema

```
create_table "subscriptions", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "fan_id"
    t.boolean "special", default: false
    t.integer "band_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "confirmed"
    t.index ["band_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_band_id"
    t.index ["fan_id"], name: "index_subscriptions_on_fan_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback in your `fan` model like:

```
after_create :subscribe
```

if you have one to many relation:

```
def subscribe
  subscriptions.where(band_id: band_id).first_or_create
end
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: i appreciate that man.   i've updated my question above to include the schema - how and where would i get the fan_id to plug it in the create line?

Comment: what are your associations? how is `fan` associated to `subscriptions`?

Comment: yes.   just tried this code, didn't work.   going to try it like create!

Comment: gave me this:  NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `fans_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x007f3150199b90> Did you mean? fan_url bands_url

Extracted source (around line #230):
228
229
230
231
232
233
              

            if options.empty?
              recipient.send(method, *args)
            else
              recipient.send(method, *args, options)
            end

Comment: That's throwing an error during registration itself. Were you able to register earlier?

Comment: sorry, had a validation on subscription i wasn't accounting for in the create.   i appreciate that man!

Comment: I m glad... (y)